# symfony 3 installer php7 zlib error: zlib extension is required for gz compressed .phar

Tags: php, symfony

`$ symfony new blog`

It printed me:

`Uncaught PharException: zlib extension is required for gz compressed .phar file "/usr/local/bin/symfony" in /usr/local/bin/symfony:9`

How I can recompile php 7 with this extension, that I installed from apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to recompile PHP to enable this extension.

Make sure you have the zlib library installed.

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev zlib1g-dev
```

find your ini file:

```
$ php --ini
```

should yield your active configuration file path, heres mine.

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /home/matt/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.3/etc

then open the php.ini file and find and enable:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

onwards from there, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php) for other config settings.

Comment: It's not working for me.
I install libgcrypt11-dev and zlib1g-dev and add "zlib.output_compression = On" in the cli configuration PHP file, that searched in "php --ini".
phpinfo() in the browser printed me ZLib Version 1.8, + fiend with ZLib Support and more.

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~wily+4

Answer (score 0):

My case was for PHP 5.6 on a BSD machine.  I needed to enable the zlib.so extension.  This extension uses the libz.so shared library.  Even if you enabled the extension, it's possible that it wasn't added to your configuration.

Add this line to /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini (or wherever this config file is kept):

```
extension=zlib.so
```

To check if it worked, use:

```
php -i
```

And look for the Phar section.